# react app on EBS - how to set react_base_app_url?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `.env` file in the local version which contains `REACT_APP_BASE_URL`

When I try to follow this guide:

[AWS Workshop - React deployment](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/ffb2b90a-c99b-499d-a077-551cbf0dee84/en-US/react-app-setup/react-app)

The static pages work. When I try to login, I get a `404` error, using inspect I can see that the app is trying to call the wrong url. It should be trying to the `django` backend.

I tried the same thing on local app and it calls the correct url. The only difference I can imagine is the `.env` is excluded.

I tried to set the environment variable in environment created for the react app on EBS, but it fails and reverts back.

I can't figure out what I might be doing wrong.